# ImportError: Failed to import test module: Django Tests

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests, hypothesis-test

I have written some tests for model, views and serializer. All tests are running fine except for the serializer tests.

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
........E
======================================================================
ERROR: testapp.tests.test_serializers (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: testapp.tests.test_serializers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "F:\Python\django-advanced\testproj\testapp\tests\test_serializers.py", line 19, in <module>
    AutoSlugField(), from_field(SlugField())
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django_extensions\db\fields\__init__.py", line 155, in __init__
    raise ValueError("missing 'populate_from' argument")
ValueError: missing 'populate_from' argument


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 9 tests in 0.034s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I am getting the above error when I run

```
python manage.py test
```

Here is my file tree -
My project name - testproj
My app name - testapp

```
    testproj/
┣ .hypothesis/
┃ ┣ examples/
┃ ┃ ┣ 89906a9970b0f6fa/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ 7210af19145ec2a8
┃ ┃ ┗ f79909d6c0990774/
┃ ┃   ┗ 7210af19145ec2a8
┃ ┗ unicode_data/
┃   ┗ 13.0.0/
┃ ┃   ┗ charmap.json.gz
┣ testapp/
┃ ┣ migrations/
┃ ┃ ┣ __pycache__/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ 0001_initial.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ 0002_alter_tag_name.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ __init__.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ __init__.cpython-38.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ 0001_initial.py
┃ ┃ ┣ 0002_alter_tag_name.py
┃ ┃ ┗ __init__.py
┃ ┣ templates/
┃ ┃ ┣ testapp/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ base.html
┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ status.html
┃ ┃ ┗ base.html
┃ ┣ tests/
┃ ┃ ┣ __pycache__/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ test_models.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ test_serializers.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ test_views.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ __init__.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ test_models.py
┃ ┃ ┣ test_serializers.py
┃ ┃ ┣ test_views.py
┃ ┃ ┗ __init__.py
┃ ┣ __pycache__/
┃ ┃ ┣ admin.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ apps.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ models.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ serializer.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ tests.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ tests.cpython-38.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ urls.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ views.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ __init__.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┗ __init__.cpython-38.pyc
┃ ┣ admin.py
┃ ┣ apps.py
┃ ┣ models.py
┃ ┣ serializer.py
┃ ┣ urls.py
┃ ┣ views.py
┃ ┣ viewsets.py
┃ ┗ __init__.py
┣ testproj/
┃ ┣ __pycache__/
┃ ┃ ┣ settings.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ settings.cpython-38.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ urls.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ urls.cpython-38.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ wsgi.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┣ __init__.cpython-310.pyc
┃ ┃ ┗ __init__.cpython-38.pyc
┃ ┣ asgi.py
┃ ┣ checks.py
┃ ┣ settings.py
┃ ┣ urls.py
┃ ┣ wsgi.py
┃ ┗ __init__.py
┣ db.sqlite3
┣ manage.py
┗ requirements.txt
```

It is running 9 tests as shown.

My test_serializers.py file

```
from django.db.models import SlugField
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField

from hypothesis import assume, given
from hypothesis.extra.django import (
    TestCase,
    from_model,
    from_field,
    register_field_strategy
)

from hypothesis.strategies import text

from ..models import Tag
from ..serializer import TagSerializer


register_field_strategy(
    AutoSlugField(), from_field(SlugField())
)

class TagSerializerTests(TestCase):

    @given(
        text(
            min_size=1,
            max_size=Tag._meta.get_field("name").max_length
        )
    )
    def test_data_serialization(self, name):
        assume(name.strip() == name)
        s1_tag = TagSerializer(data={name: "name"})
        self.assertTrue(s1_tag.is_valid(), s1_tag.errors)
        tag = s1_tag.save()
        s2_tag = TagSerializer(tag)
        self.assertTrue(s2_tag.data[name], "name")
    
    @given(from_model(Tag))
    def test_model_serialization(self, tag):
        assume(tag.name.strip() == tag.name)
        s1_tag = TagSerializer(tag)
        self.assertTrue(tag.name, s1_tag.data["name"])
        self.assertTrue(tag.slug, s1_tag.data["slug"])
        tag.delete()
        s2_tag = TagSerializer(data=s1_tag.data)
        self.assertTrue(s2_tag.is_valid(), s2_tag.errors)
        new_tag = s2_tag.save()
        self.assertTrue(tag.name, new_tag.name)
        self.assertTrue(tag.slug, new_tag.slug)
```

I do not know why it is running test_models and test_views tests but not serializers.

My settings.py file for reference -

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-@j#vm2#s=c*r+uijybeq)&ym&j1puy*i41mi2dy!pu7dn*3t_t'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'testapp.apps.TestappConfig',
    'django_extensions',
    'rest_framework'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testproj.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testproj.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': str(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"))
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Edit: Included models.py field because of the ValueError mentioned in the log.

```
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField
from django.urls import reverse

class Tag(models.Model):

    name =  models.CharField(max_length=31, unique=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(
        max_length=31,
        populate_from=["name"]
        )
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        url = reverse("tag_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
        return url
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 19 of your test module is `register_field_strategy(AutoSlugField(), from_field(SlugField()))`.
You try to create an instance of AutoSlugField with no argument, but a `populate_from` named parameter is mandatory.
See the implementation: https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/main/django_extensions/db/fields/__init__.py#L155

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I provided the parameter AutoSlugField(populate_from=["name"]). Now I am getting this error - TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class. So the error is clear but it is showing error in the hypothesis site package file. So, I dont know where I have to provide class as a parameter.